# Duplicate names - exported and non-exported (Wrapping exported functions in namespace)

Tags: typescript

How to have different exported and non-exported functions with the same name?

---

Consider the following:

```js
namespace MyGreatNamespace {
    function externallyCalled<T extends (...args) => Promise<void>>(f: T): T {
        return <T>async function externallyCalled(...args) {
            try {
                // setup();
                return await f.apply(this, args);
            } finally {
                // cleanup();
            }
        };
    }

    // Duplicate identifier 'DoSomething'.ts(2300)
    export const DoSomething = externallyCalled(DoSomething);
    function DoSomething() {}
        // ...
    }
}
```

Typescript returns two `Duplicate identifier 'DoSomething'.ts(2300)` errors.

However the output Javascript is as expected:

```js
var MyGreatNamespace;
(function (MyGreatNamespace) {
    function externallyCalled(f) {
        return async function externallyCalled(...args) {
            try {
                // setup();
                return await f.apply(this, args);
            }
            finally {
                // cleanup();
            }
        };
    }

    MyGreatNamespace.DoSomething = externallyCalled(DoSomething);
    function DoSomething() { }
    // ...
})(MyGreatNamespace || (MyGreatNamespace = {}));
```

I can use `// @ts-ignore` but that could potentially suppress real errors.

Is there a more "typescripty" way to do this?

Comment: What prevent you from giving a different name to the internal function?

Comment: I'd like to prevent the exported function from being called internally by mistake - `setup()` and `cleanup()` shouldn't be called multiple times on the same call chain. Also, trivially, having a prefix or suffix would be ugly.